# With cmake: how could I write a test to verify that a class is abstract?

Tags: c++, testing, cmake, automated-tests

I'm wondering whether I could write a .cpp file that attempts to instantiate an abstract class:

```
// file: test_ensure_A_is_abstract.cpp
class A { void foo() = 0; };
int main() { new A; }

// a simple shell script would look like this, but that is missing all the
// options cmake normally generates (-I, -g, -c, -o, ...)
if g++ test_ensure_A_is_abstract.cpp; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi
```

and then have cmake try to compile it. My point here is that I want to prove that the class is and remains abstract so one cannot ever instantiate it.

I know how to create a valid target, but I am wondering whether there would be a way to run cmake for a target known to be invalid? Anyone has done that before?

---

Update:

As per steveire answer and comments below, I wrote my own module to do the work and make sure that the class is really abstract (instead of counting on any compiler failure as indication of an abstract class.) So we have to have an error message that match a specific error. I support 4 of them, 2 that clearly make the class abstract (at least one function is pure virtual) and another 2 which view protected and private constructors as making a kind of abstract class (just like abstract classes, you cannot do a new <class name>.

You can find that module in the Snap! C++ git here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapCMakeModules/Modules/

It is named **CheckCXXAbstractClass.cmake**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/try_compile.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CheckCXXSourceCompiles.html

```
check_cxx_source_compiles(
    "class A { void foo() = 0; };\nint main() { new A; }"
    BUILT_ABSTRACT
)
if (BUILT_ABSTRACT)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "A can be instantiated, but should be abstract.")
endif()
```

You can `#include "A"` if you set the `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES` variable appropriately.

Comment: Nope, it works with about CMake 2.4. I linked to 3.0 documentation.

Comment: I have 2.8.11.2 on Ubuntu 13.10 and it tells me that it doesn't know check_cxx_source_compiles(). That being said, there is a try_compile() which seems to do the job. So I can use that.

Comment: You need `include(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)` before using the macro.

Comment: Alright! I got it to work in my environment. Only there could be other errors and thus the test "passes" even though said error is something else altogether. The FAIL_REGEX would not prevent the error from g++ from taking precedence. I think I need to use try_compile(), get the stderr output, and then make sure it says "cannot allocate an object of abstract type", then I can say that the test passed... But I see that the check_cXX_source_compiler() is defined in terms of try_compile() so I can use that to make that work as expected.